# Java boolean conditions in loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, boolean

I am trying to calculates and returns where two DNA sequences of equal lengths differ. For example, given strings "ATGT" and "GTGA", the result should be array { true, false, false, true }. I am getting an error of False/true cannot be resolved to a variable heres what i got so far

```
/**
   * Calculates and returns where two DNA sequences of equal lengths differ. For
   * example, given strings "ATGT" and "GTGA", the result should be array
   * { true, false, false, true }.
   * 
   * @param dna1 a String representing a DNA sequence of arbitrary length (equal
   *          to dna2's length), containing only the characters A, C, G and T
   * @param dna2 a String representing a DNA sequence of arbitrary length (equal
   *          to dna1's length), containing only the characters A, C, G and T
   * @return an array of boolean values, of length equivalent to both
   *         parameters' lengths, containing true in each subscript where the
   *         parameter strings differ, and false where they do not differ
   */
  public static boolean[] mutationPoints(String dna1, String dna2) {
      boolean [] mutPoint =  new boolean [dna1.length()]; 
      for( int i = 0; i < i; i++) {
          if( dna1 != dna2) {
              mutPoint[i] = False; 
          }
          else if (dna1 == dna2) {
              mutPoint[i] = True; 
          }
      }
```

Comment: Use lower case `true` & `false`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using  `for( int i = 0; i < i; i++) {`  This is always 0

Comment: Lowercase both `true` and `false`, but the next mystery will be the loop condition ` i < i`

Comment: Use equals to compare two Strings and also your loop is mysteriously built. We never enter in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following algorithm:

```
String dna1 = "ATGT";
        String dna2 = "GTGA";

        if(dna1.length() != dna2.length()) return;

        boolean [] mutPoint =  new boolean [dna1.length()];
        for( int i = 0; i < dna1.length(); i++) {
            if( dna1.charAt(i) == dna2.charAt(i)) {
                mutPoint[i] = false;
            }
            else {
                mutPoint[i] = true;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mutPoint));
```

It prints: `[true, false, false, true]`.

**Points to note:**

1. Loop should run for length of dna.
2. You need to check if length of two dnas is equal or not.
3. You need to compare equality for characters in the string.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the loop to run length of `mutPoint.length` I am having issues with the logic in the condition statement, should I not use `i < mutPoint.length` since I am trying to get dna1 equal to the other dna2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate `mutPoint.length` times (not `i` times in your loop). You want to compare the characters at the `i` index (not the `String`s). And you need to return the array. Something like,

```
boolean[] mutPoint = new boolean[dna1.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < mutPoint.length; i++) {
    mutPoint[i] = dna1.charAt(i) != dna2.charAt(i);
}
return mutPoint;
```

**or** like

```
char[] dna1arr = dna1.toCharArray();
char[] dna2arr = dna2.toCharArray();
boolean[] mutPoint = new boolean[dna1arr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < mutPoint.length; i++) {
    mutPoint[i] = dna1arr[i] != dna2arr[i];
}
return mutPoint;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short answer :

```
public static boolean[] mutationPoints(String dna1, String dna2) {
          boolean [] mutPoint =  new boolean [dna1.length()]; 
          for (int i = 0 ; i < mutPoint.length ; i++){
              mutPoint[i] = dna1.charAt(i) != dna2.charAt(i);
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you need to compare the dna sequence only if they are of equal length.

```
public static boolean[] mutationPoints(String dna1, String dna2) {
        if(dna1.length() == dna2.length()){
          boolean [] mutPoint =  new boolean [dna1.length()]; 
          for( int i = 0; i < dna1.length(); i++) {
              if( dna1.charAt(i)== dna2.charAt(i)) {
                  mutPoint[i] = true; 
              }

             else  {
                  mutPoint[i] = false; 
              }
          }

              return mutPoint;  }

        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        boolean abc[]=mutationPoints("AWQA","AQQA");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(abc));

      }
```

Output:

[true, false, true, true]